# Java Simple way to parse a line out of XML

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing

I've been trying to figure out how to parse out an XML file, however every article looks massively confusing.

Her is what my looks like.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
     <root-config>
      <session timeout="100" warning="30"/>
    </root-config>
```

Within my XML file, I am simply checking if the following node name exists - session.  If session exists i want to get attributes timeout and warning.

Is there a simple way of doing this in java without having to create a massive amount of code?

Comment: Have you looked at things like jdom?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the [Document Object Model](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/dom/) (DOM) API, specifically how to load an XML tree and [read data from it](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/dom/readingXML.html).

This is an example of how you can retrieve the information from the sample XML document:

```
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;

import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;

...

DocumentBuilderFactory documentBuilderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder documentBuilder = documentBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document document = documentBuilder.parse(new File("input.xml"));

NodeList sessionNodelist = document.getElementsByTagName("session");
if(sessionNodelist.getLength() > 0) {
    Element sessionElement = (Element) sessionNodelist.item(0);
    String timeout = sessionElement.getAttribute("timeout");
    String warning = sessionElement.getAttribute("warning");
    ...
}
```

The first three lines create an instance of a factory object that parses the input file and the XML tree is loaded in memory.

The remaining code traverses the tree of the document by getting the list of `session` nodes. If one exists, the attributes `timeout` and `warning` are retrieved from the `session` element. Note that an explicit cast is made for `sessionElement` to the `Element` type because we know that the type of the XML node is an element (`Node` is an interface that represents several types of XML nodes like elements and attributes).

Comment: I am testing this one out, however, what do i import since for the Element object.  Eclips doesn't like it.

Comment: @user1158745 Updated with imports.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can use jaxb? Here is a good simple example to to do xml unmarshalling

[JAXB Hello Worlkd](http://www.mkyong.com/java/jaxb-hello-world-example/)

Answer (score 0):

If session exists i will give you attributes timeout and warning.

```
  File fXmlFile = new File("D:/yourxmlfilename.xml");
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = dBuilder.parse(fXmlFile);

        doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

        System.out.println("Root element :" + doc.getDocumentElement().getNodeName());

        NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName("root-config");

        System.out.println("----------------------------");

        for (int temp = 0; temp < nList.getLength(); temp++) {
             Node nNode = nList.item(temp);
             System.out.println("\nCurrent Element :" + nNode.getNodeName());

             if(nNode.getNodeName().equals("session") ){
              // It will displays that session is present

              Element eElement = (Element) nNode;

                System.out.println("Item No : " + eElement.getElementsByTagName("timeout").item(0).getTextContent());
                System.out.println("Description : " + eElement.getElementsByTagName("warning").item(0).getTextContent());

             }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [JDOM library](http://www.jdom.org/) code is simple:

```
SAXBuilder builder = new SAXBuilder();
Document document = (Document) builder.build(new File("c:\\file.xml"));
Element rootNode = document.getRootElement();
Element eSession = rootNode.getChild("session");

// Use eSession
eSession.getAttributeValue("timeout");
```